# Can I move a container with a Java app from Linux to Windows and run it successfully?

Tags: java, docker, containers

I'm a Java developer and I'm learning about Docker container. And I understand that a container contains all the Java code and libraries to run on any environment. But also I understand that a container doesn't have its own OS, all containers share the same OS as the host. So, if my computer uses Windows all the containers share the Windows OS from my computer.

But I found a statement about containers that I don't understand: "Portability. Containers have better portability than other application hosting technologies. They can move among any systems that share the host OS type without requiring code changes. And you can not run a container that contains Linux binaries on Windows or vice versa."

So, if I create a Java app, let's say a Spring Boot app and then using Docker, I create an image and run the container on my computer that has Windows OS. After that can I run this container on a Linux machine? From what I understand it shouldn't work. Or does this depends on what exactly contain the container? And because Java is portable it should work on Linux and Windows without any problem. Can somebody explain me? Any feedback will be appreciated!

Comment: Theoretically, yes, you can run any image on any Java container, regardless of the OS.  More practically, there maybe inconsistencies in the implementation of the container that you'll need to be aware of and compensate for.  Nothing's perfect.  But generally running the same Java image on both Windows and *nix works well.

Answer (score 0):

Containers rely on the host operating system's kernel to function. So a container containing Linux binaries cannot be run directly on a Windows host and vice versa. This is primarily due to the differences in the underlying operating system kernels, system libraries, filesystem structure, etc.

Docker primarily leverages Linux kernel features, such as namespaces and cgroups, for containerization and isolation. Therefore on linux hosts, linux containers can be run directly.

While running Docker in Windows, there is an option to switch between the Windows and Linux container modes. It uses Hyper-V to provide the necessary virtualization and kernel compatibility required to run Linux containers alongside Windows containers.

> Or does this depends on what exactly contain the container?

Depends on whether the container created for the application is linux based or windows based

> So, if I create a Java app, let's say a Spring Boot app and then using Docker, I create an image and run the container on my computer that has Windows OS. After that can I run this container on a Linux machine?

Assuming that a linux container is created for the application, this would work on windows OS in the linux container mode and the same would work on linux OS as well